# How to save a modified excel file using Roo::Excel?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, excel, roo-gem

I opened an existing excel file using Roo::Excel. I was also able to modify the content. The problem is I don't know how to save it. Is Roo:Excel only meant for reading? If not, how do I save the changes?

Answer (score 1):

[Documentation](https://github.com/roo-rb/roo) says

> Roo implements read access for all common spreadsheet types.

Closest to saving, it has export to CSV, `sheet.to_csv`, that may not work if you want to save as excel.

You may want to look at [Which gem support Import/Export to xlsx file in ruby](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4644341/which-gem-support-import-export-to-xlsx-file-in-ruby) for alternatives.